# Maximum number of pairs from two sorted arrays

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

This is not an original problem. I had a complex problem which is now reduced to the following:

There are two sorted arrays, `A` and `B` with `m` and `n` elements respectively, `m = \Theta(n)`
Can an algorithm that runs in `o(mn)` time find the maximum number of pairs such that `A[i]-B[j] <= T` where T is some constant? How can this be done?

edit:

1. The pairs should be disjoint, i.e. one element can be selected at most once.
2. The algorithm should run in little-o(mn) meaning that a solution that runs in mn time is not acceptable.
3. Is it also possible to find the pairs that we select?

**Clarification:**

If the arrays are `a_1, a_2, ..., a_m` and `b_1, b_2, ..., b_n`, I need to find pairs `(a_i, b_j)` such that `|a_i - b_j| <= T`. It is not allowed to choose an element more than once. How can we maximize the number of pairs given the arrays?

Comment: Never seen little-O before: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations.  Wiki says `o(mn)` means complexity is dominated by `mn`, so that means `mn` time _is_ acceptable, and `m+n` is _not_ acceptible.  Please clarify.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, there's an epsilon factor on the right-hand side - it means that it must run _faster_ than _mn_.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset: I reread the article.  I was wrong again.  You're right.

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Nevermind, the new clarification has an absolute value, which means every answer on this page (as of right now) is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

The updated question (only use an element from either array once, get the pairs, and the absolute difference of the values must be below `T`) might be able to be done in **O(n+m)** time.  I haven't thought through the algorithm below enough to decide if it will always get the maximum number of pairs or not, but it should in most cases:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0; 

while(i < A.length){
    while(j < B.length){
        if(A[i]-B[j] <= T){
            if(A[i]-B[j] >= -1 * T){
                addPair(i, j);
                j++;//don't consider this value the next time
            }
            break;
        } 
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This can choose an element from B more than once. Moreover, there is no guarantee that it will choose a maximum set of pairs.

Comment: The latest update to the question says `|a_i - b_j| <= T`, an absolute value has been added.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal: Actually, since both i and j never decrease, it will never use any element in `A` or `B` more than once.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah! Sorry, my mistake. But still it doesn't work with the absolute value of difference. As as example, consider the following arrays: `20,30` and `35,70` with `T=10`. The algorithm will not select any pair. However, optimally the pair `(30,35)` should have been selected.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal: I wonder how I never noticed that bug in this code.  You're right, the correct answer is slightly more complicated.

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  Thanks, I didn't notice that requirement change.  I'll have to think on that.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal:  Actually, in that case it would select 2 pairs:  (20,35) and (30,70).  This is because I did not take into account the absolute value requirement.

Comment: @Briguy37 Yes, I assumed that there should be a absolute somewhere. Anyway, even `(20,35)` and `(30,70)` is not correct!

Answer (score 3):

In `O(n lg n) = O(m lg m)`: Create a balanced binary search tree from the elements of `A`, and store in each node the index of an element together with the element value. For each element of `B`, search for the greatest value that is less than or equal to `B[j] + T`. The index of this number will tell you how many numbers are smaller than or equal to this number.

Comment: "Create a balanced binary search tree" - Doesn't that take time itself?

Comment: I am looking for distinct pairs meaning that a number once selected can't be selected again.

Comment: @GigaWatt: Yes, but only `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I don't see how this will produce the correct number of pairs because it can take an element more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of pairs matching`|A[i]-B[j]| <= T`, where each `A[i]` and `B[j]` are used only once in all pairs:

```
int lastB = 0;
int result=0;
for(int a = 0; a<A.size(); ++a) {
    const int minB = A[a] - T;  
    while(lastB<B.size() && B[lastB] < minB)
        ++lastB;
    const int maxB = A[a] + T;
    if (lastB<B.size() && B[lastB] > minB) {
        ++lastB;
        ++result;
    }
}
return result;
```

This algorithm scans minimal ranges in `B`, and makes sure that no element in `B` is used twice.

Comment: Your solution finds the maximum number of pairs that I can obtain using A_max as the first element always. But I need the elements to be distinct. This means that once you select an element from one array, you are not allowed to choose that again.

Comment: Since all other elements are less than `A_max`, and I never return more than `A_max` as the result, you'll find that this returns the correct number anyway.

Comment: I don't see how it can return the correct result. e.g. consider the following arrays: `1, 2, 3, 1000` and `999, 1000, 1001, 1002` and threshold 5. If I understand your algorithm correctly, it will return the number of pairs as 4 whereas here only one pair is possible.

Comment: It will return 4, and there are four by the original question.  (1,999)  (2,1000) (3,1001) (1000,1002)   The equation was `A[i]-B[j] <= T`, and `2-1000<=5` is definitely true.  I just noticed your edit _now_ shows an absolute value, in which case this algorithm is flawed.  Then use Briguy37's answer, it's next fastest.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal: Upon discovering that Briguy37's has a (major) bug, I replaced my answer with a fixed version of his algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that this would work. I think you meant to write `b>lastB` in the `if condition`. Even then, it would return something wrong. Have a look at the following: A = {10}, B = {9,10,11}, T = 1. Your algorithm returns 3 whereas the only pair possible is either `(10,9)`, `(10,10)` or `(10,11)`